# Does jQuery ":animated" selector match items that use fadeIn() and fadeOut()?

Tags: jquery, click, fadein, fadeout, animated

I'm trying to prevent clicks on a list item while an animation is occurring. So at the top of my click handler, I want to do something like this:

```
if(!$(this).is(:animated)) {
    // handle click code here
}
```

Note the 'bang' (!) in the if statement above. I haven't tested, but I assume this will work. What I'm not sure of is whether '.is(:animated)' will return true when run against an element that is being animated via fadeIn() and fadeOut(). I know that jQuery has a .animate() function, and I assume :animated certainly works against elements animated using that function, but will it work with those using fadeIn() and fadeOut()? Thanks.

**UPDATE:** After some dramatic mis-posts, all seems well, and thanks to the reponders for all the great follow-ups and edits. In the end, I have found that, yes, :animated matches those elements animated using fadeIn() and fadeOut() because the jQuery source uses .animate() to achieve these effects. My final check was as originally posted:

```
if(!$(this).is(:animated)) {
    // handle click code here
}
```

..rather than using .not() as has been proposed in some instances (though I believe these will work as currently posted). Thanks again.

Comment: By the way, the 'bang' is called the `not operator`.

Comment: @Mega Matt, My original use of `.not()` was incorrect. I updated my answer, please check before using my code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `:animated` will return true for any sort of animation that jQuery creates. It will also do it for any plugins that animate provided they use the jQuery `animate` function.

However, you can write your code just a pinch differently to make use of jQuery:

**Edit** The `not` function is not the opposite of `is`. It filters out nodes, but still returns a jQuery object which evaluates to `true`. To use the `not` function as I originally suggested, you would have to add `.length` to the test:

```
if( $(this).not(':animated').length ) {
    // Handle click code here
}
```

Otherwise, use the function as the OP originally posted:

```
if( !$(this).is(':animated')) {
    // Handle click code here
}
```

Comment: Ah, good to know. Was not aware of the 'not' function. Thanks for the response.

Comment: you can also do if (!$(this).is(':not(:animated)')) { //handle click code }

Comment: @petersendidit So your code says: "If not `this` is not animated". So... if it _is_ animated ;) Think you left an extra `!` in there, but I get your point. Very good to know.

Comment: @dcneiner, @petersendidit Just logged on to report that the 'not' is not the opposite of 'is' as dcneiner had posted, but I see you all already beat me to :) Wish I would have logged on a little sooner because I had a *hell* of a time not understanding what was going on for a while. But as stated, !$(this).is(':animated'); works best for my purposes, so that's the way I left it. And it works fine with the fadeIn() and fadeOut(). Beats the hell out of killing and reconnecting live click events, which is what I was doing. Thanks again for the responses.

Comment: @Mega Matt, I felt horrible already.. now I feel worse! :) I wish there was a SO instant message system.

Comment: Process Improvement? :) Moderators?! I'm down.

Answer (score 2):

`:animate` will match elements which have had `fadeOut` called.

If you look in the jQuery source, you'll see that `fadeOut` simply calls `animate`.
It's defined like this:

```
// Generate shortcuts for custom animations
jQuery.each({
    slideDown: genFx("show", 1),
    slideUp: genFx("hide", 1),
    slideToggle: genFx("toggle", 1),
    fadeIn: { opacity: "show" },
    fadeOut: { opacity: "hide" }
}, function( name, props ){
    jQuery.fn[ name ] = function( speed, callback ){
        return this.animate( props, speed, callback );
    };
});
```

Comment: Did not know that fadeIn and fadeOut used animate(). Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have the if statement in there at all. You can chain the .not(':animated') before your 'click code'.

As an example, these fades would only work if the div wasn't in the process of being animated, therefore getting rid of the nasty queue problem.

```
$('a#show_me').toggle(function() {
    $('div#the_money').not(':animated').fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $('div#the_money').not(':animated').fadeOut();
});
```

It would work the same for the .click() as well.